# how to do Alert Notification for asp.net Mvc4 for database CRUD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, push-notification

I recently started with a project which is more like end to end interaction. for example if admin adds a task to the particular user(userId-> Foriegn key in task table) user should get a notifications more like a Facebook or stack overflow. how can i achieve that. Suggestions will help me from your side.
although i am building my application using asp.net MVC 4 using entity Framework ,in Razor engine. If you have any samples which is related to this please post me to my mail id(nandishs89@gmail.com).

I will waiting for you peoples valuable suggestion.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can take an idea from this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21903225/1534785

Comment: Hi Jhoon, thanks for the response, but one thing i dint understand is, how do you get unread message count. i want some thing like alert in user page in corner of his window. same as Facebook.

Comment: It depends on what you want to show like notification. For generally, create a notifation table, columns are userId, notifation text and isRead or not. when any event occur, add a notification into that table. Finally, using my answer show notifiation in page.

Comment: hi @JhoonBey  as you mentioned above about your 'idea'. Sorry to say but the link you given is broken(Not Available)..

Comment: When I posted it, it was available. Maybe that question was deleted. That was related answer to this ;(